# Comma after last item in a list?

Tags: commas

As the title states, if I have a list with a description after it like, "New coffee makers, new washing machines, dishwashers, or even toasters, are already..." should I put a comma after the last item in the list? (Toasters in the example)

Comment: This should be placed in English Language SE, not the Writing SE.

Comment: Of course, no. But why do you ask?

Comment: A great example of a sentence that would improve from a rewrite.